# How to filter the array of objects from the the main object value

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angular-filters

I am trying to make a filter using an array of object. but I am not getting the answer as per I requested.

the object the one I looping though has 3 steps of arrays. I am trying to filter them and show in the `li` element but not working. only the first step works for me.

the array is : "Name`,`SubProjects`and`Contracts` ( all are nested inside of the main object)

here is my try:

```
<div class="section filter1">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="value in values"> {{value.Name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
 <div class="section filter2">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="value in values | SubProjects"> {{$index}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
 <div class="section filter3">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="value in values | SubProjects | Contracts"> {{value.Name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

object for sample :

```
{
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "Khalifa International Stadium",
    "SubProjects": [
      {
        "Contracts": [
          {
            "CompletedPercentage": 0,
            "Id": "583",
            "Name": "LP/C21/145",
            "Phase": null
          },
          {
            "CompletedPercentage": 0,
            "Id": "529",
            "Name": "KP/B21/134",
            "Phase": null
          },
          {
            "CompletedPercentage": 0,
            "Id": "575",
            "Name": "LP/C21/142",
            "Phase": null
          }
        ],
        "Id": "2",
        "Name": "Energy Center"
      },
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WBXjyS1MmxI1ArqpAgpS?p=preview)

Comment: not sure what you mean by "value in values | SubProjects" as filter syntax is different, anyway check these two sources https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter  and    https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=angularjs%20filter%20nested%20array

Comment: I am trying to retrive the objects from the nested arrays using the filter, is it not possible?

Comment: everything is possible! check examples from same questions, try something, at least filtering main array. create jsFiddle with question, and then someone can help you.

Comment: @DmitriAlgazin there is already a plunker added in question.

Comment: to filter something, you need input at least, can't see that in plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the custom filter according to your requirement here. See [this](http://embed.plnkr.co/jme6xnY0FEeqcwjSFo6E/preview) example, and let me know if you face any issue with your case. For documentation please [check](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter). A more [simple](http://jsfiddle.net/yctchgnk/.) example with same approach.

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="search">
    <ul ng-repeat="oneauth in authorisations[0]">
        <li ng-repeat="entry in oneauth | nameFilter:search">    
     {{entry.auth.name}}</li>
  </ul>


  app.filter('nameFilter', function(){
     return function(objects, criteria){
        var filterResult = new Array();
          if(!criteria)
             return objects;

        for(index in objects) {
            if(objects[index].auth.name.indexOf(criteria) != -1) // filter by name only
               filterResult.push(objects[index]);
            }
           console.log(filterResult);

       return filterResult;  
    }    
 });
```